# update value simultaneously to table using MVC ajax async

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to update values to sql table from queue simultaneously using Ajax async. It's not working for me.

My code

```
 function ProcessQueue() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("process", "MyAccount")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: true,
    });
    setTimeout(function () { ProcessQueue(); }, 900);
}
```

Controller :

```
 public void process()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            calling table update function here. ....
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action is static, just removed that and it will probably work assuming that everything else is OK. You also have a non-optional parameter in you action that you might want to give something to work with, doesn't look like you giving it anything.

Comment: I removed that parameter and static. It's not working. One time also not hit my action.

Comment: Now it's calling. but it seems not working Async. it's waiting for comlete that process

Comment: Where are you getting the wait exactly? You have a timeout at the moment in your script, are you receving some additional waiting outside of that or what?